# How to move code from gradle task configuration step to task execution

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I have gradle task:

```
task immportMyData(type: Exec) {
def dumnp= ""

new File("${System.env.MY_HOME}/export").eachDir() { dir ->
    dumpName = dir.getName()
}

workingDir "${System.env.MY_HOME}/../test"
standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

 ext.output = {
    return standardOutput.toString()
 } 
}
```

...

As I understand its task configuration, because its executed every time.

So, is there any way how to move code from conflagration step to task body (execution step) ?
Some thinks like this.

```
task immportMyData(type: Exec) << {
   //code from configuration
}

another worlds 

   task immportMyData(type: Exec) **<<** {
def dumnp= ""

new File("${System.env.MY_HOME}/export").eachDir() { dir ->
    dumpName = dir.getName()
}

workingDir "${System.env.MY_HOME}/../test"
standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

 ext.output = {
    return standardOutput.toString()
 } 
}
```

I've checked [gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html), but no luck

Comment: What exactly you'd like to move? It seems that the task is configured well.

Comment: Yeap its works, but i don't want to execute its every time. So I want to move it to task.  Something like this:
http://pastebin.com/raw/iuvTStCK

Comment: It won't work that way. Configuration is done every time, however the task is run only once.

Comment: Putting your code inside brackets of << {} should do the trick - << is the same as doLast, i.e. it defines action that should be executed the last during task execution. However, I don't see why do you need Exec task type.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have misunderstood what the `Exec` task does. `Exec` is for running an *external* command, i.e. another process. As such, it needs you to specify its `commandLine` property in order for it to do anything at execution time. See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) for more info.

It looks like what you're actually trying to do is "run some code during task execution", which can be achieved using a regular (non-`Exec`) task. Something like this:

```
task importMyData {
    //Code to configure task

    doLast {
        //Code to run at execution time, maybe this?:
        new File("${System.env.MY_HOME}/export").eachDir() { dir ->
            ext.dump = dir.getName()
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.